# Require including <mylibrary/mylibrary.h> instead of <mylibrary.h> inside Cmake project that links to mylibrary

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a very simple c++ shared library with a `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)
project(mylibrary)

add_library (mylibrary src/mylibrary.h src/mylibrary.cpp)
target_include_directories(mylibrary PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src)
```

Now in the project that uses this library I link to this library with `target_link_libraries(myapp mylibrary)` and then I can include the library with `#include <mylibrary.h>`. However, to visually separate all library includes I want to (have to) use `#include <mylibrary/mylibrary.h>`, even though mylibrary.h is not inside a folder called mylibrary. Is there a way to achieve this with Cmake?

Comment: Inside of the src  folder do you have a mylibrary folder? To get this to work you need to move the header into a folder named mylibrary.

Comment: @drescherjm No, I was hoping for a different method of achieving the same end result